# Set an Empty SRC on MediaElement.js Player?

Tags: html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I have a single audio player on a page. Users can select an audio track to load. In between selections, I would like to set the source of the audio player to nothing. Passing an empty string to "setSrc" produces the undesired effect of a "Download File" message.

So what is the best way to achieve this? Currently I am passing a string to "setSrc" that I know is not a file, and this kind of produces the desired effect, but is obviously not ideal.

https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/587

Answer (score 2):

I had a related issue. I built an audio player which loads tracks dynamically. Problem was I had to set something as a src when creating the audio tag. I even tried using base64 encoded empty mp3, only to learn that it will make the Flash fallback throw exceptions.

It's not very well documented, but eventually I realised that if I initialise the MediaElement with parameter 'type' set to 'audio/mp3' (in my case), there is no need to set src initially.

From what I can see in mediaelement.js, it only requires the src for determining media type e.g. (.mp3, .mpg etc).

So to answer your question, once you've set type explicitly, you should be able to set src to "nothing".